# Building a formula to pass n bits though the minimum number of circuts

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design

I have a circuit `X` which has `4` inputs `A0,B0,A1,B1` and `2` outputs `A2,B2`. For `n` of `A,B` bits, I need them to pass through `X`.  I'm trying to build an equation on how many circuits `X` I need for `n` bits. For example, for `n=8` we need `7` circuits:

[image]

I found out that for `2<=n<=7` we need `n-1` `X` cuirits, but I know that for `n=32` we need to get `30`. What is the right formula?

Comment: So each level is half the number of the previous level. Now sum these up. Hint: Geometric progression.

Comment: I don't understand what the "X" boxes are supposed to do. How is the output of an X box related to the input of that box? How do you **know** that you need 30 X boxes for n=32, because I am skeptical of that answer.

Comment: Indeed, for 32 bits you need 15 boxes. At least if the other information in the question is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Each of your X boxes reduces 4 input signals to 2.

To put it another way, each X box reduces the total number of signals by 2.

This result is the same *whatever* arrangement of X boxes you use: a fat tree (like the one you drew) or a long thin chain.

If you have 2n inputs, you will always need n-1 boxes if you want only 2 outputs.

Your “n=32” solution must therefore be wrong somehow.